# Rollback on elasticsearch bulk insert failure

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bulkinsert, rollback

Use case: Right now I am using Python elasticsearch API form bulk insert.
I have try except wrapped around my bulk insert code but whenever any exception comes elastisearch doesn't rollback inserted document.
And also doesn't try to insert the remaining documents other than the corrupted document which throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing, a bulk queries contains a list of queries to insert / update or delete documents.

elasticsearch is not a database (no ACID / no transaction etc..), so you must create a rollback feature yourself.

Comment: I always thought elasticsearch was a nosql 'database', isn't it?

Comment: database means nothing, a file is a database, if you put json in it, this is a nosql database ^^